# Android how to get gps Bearing

Tags: android, gps

I'm building an android application that requires my location and bearing.

When I use `location.getBearing()` the result is 0.0

The google maps application seems to have my bearing just fine when I walk around the house. My question is how can I get my bearing so it works as flawlessly as in google maps.

I've tried calculating it by using a previous known location with a distance of at least 2 meters, and getting the bearing to that location but it's all over the place.

Thanks

Comment: Google Maps probably uses the compass to show your heading. Go out and move far enough and the GPS based bearing becomes available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the android developer page

> Bearing is the horizontal direction of travel of this device, and is not related to the device orientation. It is guaranteed to be in the range (0.0, 360.0] if the device has a bearing.
>
> If this location does not have a bearing then 0.0 is returned.

I would suggest you use the `hasBearing()` call to determine if you can use the bearing.

**edit**

I would change your `requestLocationUpdates` parameters reasonable values. Read here : [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

minTime and minDistance should be used to limit using too much of the devices battery. I would suggest ( 2000, 2.0 ) respectfully. (2 seconds or 2 meters)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);`

The first 0 represents the minimum time before it updates again. By setting it at 0, for some reason the gps isn't getting the bearing. The problem is resolved by simply changing it to a higher number. Like this;
`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2,0,locationListener);`